# Getting issues via email stopped working after email account password update

Tags: email, jira

We had a fully working Jira Service Desk installation (JIRA Service Desk Application v3.6.1) for years and on Friday we changed the password of the associated email account ithelp@...

Once the change was done on the Exchange server we updated the password on system-Outgoing Mail and system-Incoming Mail, provided the latest password by clicking on checkbox adjacent to Change Password. After entering the password, click on Update button.. The test in both cases says its working.

[image: Connection test]

If we check Mail audit log for ithelp@... then we see.

[image: Mail audit log welcome screen]

If we do a test there then:

[image: Mail audit log after test]

And the "view log" shows:

[image: Mail audit detailed log]

What have we tried?

We went through https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/troubleshooting-jira-service-desk-incoming-mail-790960076.html?_ga=2.74568658.1933816762.1551665594-977289960.1550604024 without success.

Restarting Tomcat.

Rebooting the server.

Deleting and recreating the configuration for IMAP.

Configuring the IMAP settings using IP instead of server name.

If you know what could be the problem or if you know what we are missing your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log into Jira Service Desk with elevated rights. (administrative rights)
2. Select projects -> IThelp
3. Select email requests.
4. Under custom email addresses click the edit.
5. Change the password to the new password set for IThelp. Click next
6. Select the email request type as Email Request